# Bind entire form inputs to URL/GetParams in AngularDart?

Tags: angular, angular-dart

I have an AngularDart application, and I want to bind form input to the URL (the form represents settings). This is so that the user can share a link to another user (and thereby sharing what he/she has input on the form).

For example, I have a form, and I am looking for something like this.

```
Settings:

<input type='text' name='username' [value]="urlGetParams[username]" />

<input type='checkbox' name='enableStats' [value]="urlGetParams[enableStats]" />
```

Does something like this exist? Onchange() I want to change the URL, and when the user visits that URL, it "loads" that form.

Comment: are you wanting to actively change the URL as the user types?  that seems odd TBH.  OR were you wanting a button after filling out the form to generate a URL to share?  Now to "pre-load" a form based on whats in the URL.. that is typically done with Angular Routing and I can give you an example of how to do it that way if you'd like.

Comment: "pre-load A form based on whats in the URL" is half of what I want, the other is generating & redirecting the URL based on the form (upon clicking "Submit" or better, automatically when you modify the form but I doubt it is possible?). I'd love an example.

I'm new to Angular (started a week ago).

Answer (score 0):

Create a model that represent all form values.

```
class Search {
    String username;
    bool enableStats;

    Search()

    factory Search.fromJson(Map json) => Search()
        ..username=json['username']
        ..enableStats=json['enableStats']=='true';
}
```

Then in your component, populate it with queryparams that you previously got from OnActivate():

```
void OnActivate(RouterState previous, RouterState current) {
    var search = Search.fromJson(current.queryParameters);
}
```

In your template:

```
<input type='text' name='username' [value]="search.username" />

<input type='checkbox' name='enableStats' [value]="search.enableStats" />
```

I would recommend using [ngModel & Controlgroup (angular form)](https://angulardart.dev/guide/forms) to make your form and add some security checks

Comment: My AppComponent implemented `OnActivate` and overridden the `onActivated(prev, curr)` method, but the onActivated component was never called (checked it with print statements). I want the onActivate to load when the page first loads (when the user first visits the website).

Comment: P.S. Do I need something else apart from what you've written?

Comment: Oh, maybe I need to wrap my entire application in a Router component.

Comment: I don't think the AppComponent uses OnActivate, it's the top parent container who contains the router outlet, so the routes begin to this router outlet. You need to make a component that is connected to a route like [heroComponent](https://angulardart.dev/tutorial/toh-pt5#libsrchero_componentdart-onactivate) in the hero tutorial.